# Pre populate a lookup field with CPQ Quote

Tags: quote, cpq, standard

Usually in Salesforce when we click on "new" button from parent object to create a child object, the lookup field is pre populated with the ID of parent object.

But in the case of Quote object when I try to create a new Quote from its parent object (that is a custom object called Function__c) the lookup field is not populated. I didn't find any trace of why in the documentation. If it's impossible I would like to know why to explain in detail why I can't do it.

Comment: If you are creating it from a quick action you can predefined field option.

Comment: Is that just a fixed value or can it take the ID of the quote record?